# Entity Framework 5 2 equals virtual property

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I'm using Code First and write some classes  with 2 virtuals users fields
 (just example, i deleted useless part )

```
 public class User
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// User constructor.
        /// </summary>
        public User()
        {
            this.History = new List<History>();
        }
       public virtual IList<History> History { get; set; }
    }
public class History
    {
        public virtual User User { get; set; }

        public virtual User TechnicalExpert { get; set; }
    }
```

and then i have problem because Entity FrameWork didnt bind it correctly even i use FluentApi

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<History>()
                .HasOptional(g => g.User).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
  modelBuilder.Entity<History>()
                .HasOptional(g => g.TechnicalExpert).WithMany().WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
```

and if write

```
 string techExpert = dayHistory != null ?
     history.TechnicalExpert.FullName : Resources.NotAssigned;
```

He give me a User Full Name.Where is mistake?
In Db i have normal foreign key Keys:

```
[FK_dbo.History_dbo.Users_TechnicalExpert_UserId]
[FK_dbo.History_dbo.Users_User_UserId]
```

Comment: Have you queried the DB directly to make sure it's not a data issue?

Comment: in DB all OK.User_UserId and TechnicalExpert_UserId fields